# How to add an int32-compatible and versatile, closure-based numeric operation support through SRTP in F#

Tags: f#

Context: the other day (a few weeks back, I was playing with an algorithm to extract the digits for a given number depend on different types).

Note: there is no practical purpose for doing this other than playing with the F# SRTP.

```ml
type Numbers =
    static member Ten (_ : uint8)   = 10uy
    static member Ten (_ : uint16)  = 10us
    static member Ten (_ : uint32)  = 10ul
    static member Ten (_ : uint64)  = 10UL
    static member Ten (_ : int8)    = 10y
    static member Ten (_ : int16)   = 10s
    static member Ten (_ : int32)   = 10l
    static member Ten (_ : int64)   = 10L
    static member Ten (_ : single)  = 10f
    static member Ten (_ : double)  = 10.
    static member Ten (_ : decimal) = 10m
    // static member Ten (_ : bigint)  = 10I //bug?

let inline (/%) dividend divisor = let quotient = dividend / divisor in quotient, dividend - quotient * divisor

let inline divRemBy10 x =
    let inline call (_: ^T, x: ^I) = ((^T or ^I) : (static member Ten: _ -> _) x)
    x /% (call (Unchecked.defaultof<Numbers>, x))

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Digits =
    let inline (|Positive|Zero|Negative|) number =
        if number > LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then Positive
        elif number = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then Zero
        else Negative

    let inline toDigits number =
        let generator oldQuotient =
            let newQuotient, newRemainder = divRemBy10 oldQuotient
            if newQuotient = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero &&
               newRemainder = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
               then None
            else Some(newRemainder, newQuotient)
        let alternateNegative i digit =
            if i > LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then digit * -LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
            else digit
        match number with
        | Positive -> number |> Seq.unfold generator |> Seq.rev
        | Zero     -> Seq.singleton LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        | Negative -> number |> Seq.unfold generator |> Seq.rev |> Seq.mapi alternateNegative


[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    [ -465l; 10l; 0l; -10l; 1l; 42l; Int32.MaxValue; Int32.MinValue ]
    |> List.map (fun number -> number, Digits.toDigits number |> String.join "")
    |> List.iter(fun (number, digitsString) -> printfn $"%d{number}=%s{digitsString}")

    [ 10y; 0y; -10y; 1y; 42y; SByte.MaxValue; SByte.MinValue ]
    |> List.map (fun number -> number, Digits.toDigits number |> String.join "")
    |> List.iter(fun (number, digitsString) -> printfn $"%d{number}=%s{digitsString}")

    [ 10s; 0s; -10s; 1s; 42s; Int16.MaxValue; Int16.MinValue ]
    |> List.map (fun number -> number, Digits.toDigits number |> String.join "")
    |> List.iter(fun (number, digitsString) -> printfn $"%d{number}=%s{digitsString}")

    [ 10L; 0L; -10L; 1L; 42L; Int64.MaxValue; Int64.MinValue ]
    |> List.map (fun number -> number, Digits.toDigits number |> String.join "")
    |> List.iter(fun (number, digitsString) -> printfn $"%d{number}=%s{digitsString}")
    0
```

So far, so good the code above is working as expected.

That being said, I'm wondering how I can refactor it so that I could benefit from something that would turn an `int32` like e.g. `10` to the equivalent of `Ten` function implementation for each underlying numeric primitives.

```ml
let inline divRemBy x (i: int32) = ...
```

and at the call site, it could become then:

```ml
divRemBy oldQuotient 10
```

But I can't really figure out how, any idea?

Also, wondering if what I'm aiming at achieving is actually something doable, or not?

Comment: There is a `Math.DivRem` and a `BigInteger.DivRem`, but you probably know that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your divisor is now non-generic, you can no longer use the dividend type's division operator. Instead, I think your best bet is to convert everything into a "safe" type, use the safe type's division operator, and then convert back to the dividend's type afterwards. This introduces the possibility of rounding/truncation errors during the conversions, but, fortunately, it looks like we can accommodate all of your test cases using `int64` as the safe type (including `bigint` support as well).

First, here's the safe division function:

```ml
let div (convert, dividend: int64, divisor: int64) =
    let quotient = dividend / divisor
    convert quotient, convert (dividend - quotient * divisor)
```

Next we change `Numbers` so that it calls `div` with the right conversion function for each dividend type:

```ml
type Numbers =
    static member Div (x: uint8, y: int64) = div (uint8, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: uint16, y: int64) = div (uint16, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: uint32, y: int64) = div (uint32, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: int8, y: int64) = div (int8, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: int16, y: int64) = div (int16, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: int32, y: int64) = div (int32, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: int64, y: int64) = div (int64, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: single, y: int64) = div (single, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: double, y: int64) = div (double, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: decimal, y: int64) = div (decimal, int64 x, y)
    static member Div (x: bigint, y: int64) = div (bigint, int64 x, y)
```

We can now implement `divRemBy` the way you want:

```ml
let inline divRemBy x (y: int) =
    let inline call (_: ^T, x: ^I) =
        ((^T or ^I) : (static member Div: _ * _ -> _) (x, int64 y))
    call (Unchecked.defaultof<Numbers>, x)
```

And the call site also looks the way you want:

```ml
let newQuotient, newRemainder = divRemBy oldQuotient 10
```

For fun, I changed the base to binary (`divRemBy oldQuotient 2`), and I think the result is still correct:

```
-465=-111010001
10=1010
0=0
-10=-1010
1=1
42=101010
2147483647=1111111111111111111111111111111
-2147483648=-10000000000000000000000000000000
10=1010
0=0
-10=-1010
1=1
42=101010
127=1111111
-128=-10000000
10=1010
0=0
-10=-1010
1=1
42=101010
32767=111111111111111
-32768=-1000000000000000
10=1010
0=0
-10=-1010
1=1
42=101010
9223372036854775807=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
-9223372036854775808=-1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```